# Why is an empty TCP segment at right edge of receive window not acceptable?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, transport-protocol, layer4, rfc

The TCPv4 specification (RFC 793) [classifies a received segment as unacceptable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-69) if it has zero length, a sequence number equal to `RCV.NXT`+`RCV.WND` while the receive window is not zero (second row in the table).

This essentially means that the segment will be discarded, other than possibly sending an `ACK`. No `ACK` processing or send window update will be done.

What is the justification of this?

Consider this scenario:

1. Host A sends all possible data segments to host B, just exhausting the  receive window of B.
2. Host A shortly also sends an empty segment, e.g. a window update or acknowledgement of received data. This segment has sequence number equal to the right edge of the receive window of host B (`RCV.NXT`+`RCV.WND`), since it was set to the latest `SND.NXT` of host A.
3. The mentioned data packets are lost in the network or delayed, and host B receives the empty segment first.
4. Host B will classify the empty segment as not acceptable, and drop it, ignoring any acknowledgement or window update.

This seems to be particularly problematic, because the receiver will typically [ignore seemingly older window updates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-72) based on the combination of sequence number and acknowledgement number. But just those window updates that won't get filtered out (highest sequence number) would be dropped even earlier due to segments not being considered acceptable.

Is there some part that I am not understanding correctly? Is this scenario really possible?

Comment: I'm not following you. The second line in the table seems to indicate that if the `RCV.WND` is greater than `0`, then a zero length segment would be accepted. Your condition 1 says that the `RCV.WND` would be `0`. The text under the table says, "_If the RCV.WND is zero, no segments will be acceptable, but special allowance should be made to accept valid ACKs, URGs and RSTs._"

Comment: @RonMaupin I am concerned about zero-length segments when `RCV.WND` is nonzero - empty segments with sequence numbers up to but not including RCV.NXT+RCV.WND will be accepted. Why not accept a zero-length segment with sequence number RCV.NXT+RCV.WND? It might be a window update, or acknowledgement of received data. Instead the spec seems to prefer for the receive window to be raised, before accepting another ack or window update from the remote.

Comment: But, in your question, #1 means that `RCV.WND` is `0`. "_...just exhausting the receive window of B._" If the receive window is exhausted, then you cannot accept any more segments.

Comment: @RonMaupin I did not mean that. By "exhausting the receive window", I mean that A sends on its way all the data that B is ready to accept. As soon as A sends that last segment which ends exactly at `RCV.NXT`+`RCV.WND`, any further empty segment will have sequence number equal to `RCV.NXT`+`RCV.WND`, and hence may be deemed unacceptable by B. That is, until either B extends the receive window, or all the transmitted data are accepted by B leaving it with a zero window which would then make empty segments from A acceptable again, according to the first row in the table.

Comment: Basically, you are wanting TCP to accept a segment, empty or not, for the next receive window before you have finished with the first receive window. If you read the fourth line in the table you will see that doesn't work (you don't use negative numbers for a length).

Comment: Yes that's my point, the question is about why this is so. It seems like a "spec bug" to me, since such zero-length segments at the edge of the receive window is expected to be received in case of packet loss or reordering - it can be sent due to ACK of received data or due to a window update.

I've looked at Linux kernel and it seems to have a much relaxed check in place allowing this: see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/4935e04ef431c7980ba6e8145ad4c697abccf6b9/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c#L5192

Comment: I don't think it does make sense to allow a segment for the next window when you have not finished the current window. That is how the RFC was written, and it makes sense to me. Have you checked any of the many follow-on RFCs for TCP to see if it has changed over the years. If it hasn't changed, and you still object, anyone, including you, can submit a proposed an RFC. What Linux does, or does not, do is not particularly relevant here because host configurations are off-topic. Linux actually violates many RFCs in how it does some things, and I have noticed that much networking in it is buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Segment in this context refers to PAYLOAD OF TCP.
L=0 toss it.
Segment outside of window toss it. S<RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
but that is where they mess up in the spec, and it gets fixed in a later RFC.
Any S<RCV.NXT+RCV.WND will be accepted.  Like a retransmission.
ACKs, SACKS, and window updates are always processed.
(The max is used to keep things straight in out-of-order situations)

Hope you graduated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's that table:

> ```
>     Segment Receive  Test
>     Length  Window
>     ------- -------  -------------------------------------------
>
>        0       0     SEG.SEQ = RCV.NXT
>
>        0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>
>       >0       0     not acceptable
>
>       >0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>                   or RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ+SEG.LEN-1 < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
> ```

According to your scenario, for the packet of interest, `SEG.SEQ` = `RCV.NXT`+`RCV.WND`, `SEG.LEN` = 0, and `RCV.WND` > 0.

So yes, we need to look at the second row, and indeed, that test doesn't pass, which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Maybe report an [erratum](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=793&rec_status=0)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a situation where host A sends an empty segment in your scenario.

A is supposed to send packets up to the receiver window and then wait for ACKs [your item 1]. If nothing is received in response there are retransmissions, and retransmissions have sequence number < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND. A will not send an empty packet with sequence number outside of receiver window if it did not receive anything from B. So, your item 2 cannot happen.

If anything is received by A, that means that A has received an ACK (which updates SND.UNA) and with it new value of receiver window, so A either knows new receiver window or that receiver window is empty. This means next sequence number will be inside receiver window. Thus it will not result in missing check in line 2. Thus again, item 2 will not happen.

If A knows that receiver window is empty, it will indeed send a zero-length packet called zero-window probe. But this is conditioned on A receiving a zero-length receiver window from B, so again your situation cannot happen. Also, window probes are ACKed, so again both A and B know that the receiver window is zero, and A can select a sequence number SEG.SEQ = RCV.NXT.

So, to summarize, it is actually a sender error, if the sender sends a segment with a sequence number outside of receiver window.